# netconf getting a parser huge_tree error message

Tags: python, cisco, netconf

I am getting an error when I attempt to push a config to an ASR9K running IOS XR Software, Version 5.3.4.
The payload prints out without any issues and get's interpreted correctly by Python.  The problem is when I send it the router, it doesn't like it for some reason.

```
from ncclient import manager
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import os

# netconf Connection Manager
netconf_connection = manager.connect(host='10.22.108.13',
                     port=830,
                     username='admin',
                     password='super',
                     device_params={'name': 'iosxr'},
                     hostkey_verify=False,
                     look_for_keys=False)

#
netconf_data = {
    "carrier_vlan": 201,
    "customer_vlan": 5000,
    "HUB_WAN1_PUBLIC_IP": "40.40.40.40",
    "customer": "FirstNetConfTest",
    "PRIMARY_TRANSIT": "41.41.41.41",
    "neighbor_IP": "41.41.41.42",
    "Location": "ATL"
    }

template_dir = f"{os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}/templates"

j2_env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(template_dir), trim_blocks=True)
netconf_payload = j2_env.get_template('new_config.j2').render(netconf_data)

print(netconf_payload)

response = netconf_connection.edit_config(netconf_payload, target="running")
```

> #################### ERROR ############################ Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/netconf_config.py",
> line 38, in  response =
> netconf_connection.edit_config(netconf_payload, target="running") File
> "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ncclient/manager.py",
> line 246, in execute return cls(self.session, File
> "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ncclient/operations/edit.py",
> line 65, in request node.append(validated_element(config, ("config",
> qualify("config")))) File
> "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ncclient/xml.py",
> line 150, in validated_element ele = to_ele(x) File
> "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ncclient/xml_.py",
> line 129, in to_ele return x if etree.iselement(x) else
> etree.fromstring(x.encode('UTF-8'), parser=_get_parser(huge_tree))
> File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3237, in lxml.etree.fromstring File
> "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1896, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
> File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1784, in lxml.etree._parseDoc File
> "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1141, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc
> File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 615, in
> lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc File
> "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 725, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult File
> "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 654, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError File
> "", line 1 lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not
> found, line 1, column 1

############## PAYLOAD ###############################

```
XML>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Request>
    <Set>
        <Configuration>
            <InterfaceConfigurationTable>
                <InterfaceConfiguration>
                    <Naming>
                        <Active>act</Active>
                        <InterfaceName>Bundle-Ether4.2015000</InterfaceName>
                    </Naming>
                    <InterfaceModeNonPhysical>Default</InterfaceModeNonPhysical>
                    <Description>FirstNetConfTest</Description>
                    <IPV4Network>
                        <Addresses>
                            <Primary>
                                <Address>40.40.40.40</Address>
                                <Netmask>255.255.255.254</Netmask>
                            </Primary>
                        </Addresses>
                    </IPV4Network>
                    <VLANSubConfiguration>
                        <VLANIdentifier>
                            <VlanType>VLANTypeDot1q</VlanType>
                            <FirstTag>201</FirstTag>
                            <SecondTag>5000</SecondTag>
                        </VLANIdentifier>
                    </VLANSubConfiguration>
                </InterfaceConfiguration>
                <InterfaceConfiguration>
                    <Naming>
                        <Active>act</Active>
                        <InterfaceName>Bundle-Ether4.2015001</InterfaceName>
                    </Naming>
                    <InterfaceModeNonPhysical>Default</InterfaceModeNonPhysical>
                    <Description>FirstNetConfTest_WAN-Transit</Description>
                    <IPV4Network>
                        <Addresses>
                            <Primary>
                                <Address>41.41.41.41</Address>
                                <Netmask>255.255.255.254</Netmask>
                            </Primary>
                        </Addresses>
                    </IPV4Network>
                    <VLANSubConfiguration>
                        <VLANIdentifier>
                            <VlanType>VLANTypeDot1q</VlanType>
                            <FirstTag>201</FirstTag>
                            <SecondTag>5001</SecondTag>
                        </VLANIdentifier>
                    </VLANSubConfiguration>
                </InterfaceConfiguration>
            </InterfaceConfigurationTable>
            <BGP>
                <Instance>
                    <Naming>
                        <InstanceName>default</InstanceName>
                    </Naming>
                    <InstanceAS>
                        <Naming>
                            <AS>0</AS>
                        </Naming>
                        <FourByteAS>
                            <Naming>
                                <AS>11696</AS>
                            </Naming>
                            <BGPRunning>true</BGPRunning>
                            <DefaultVRF>
                                <Global>
                                    <GlobalAFTable>
                                        <GlobalAF>
                                            <Naming>
                                                <AFName>IPv4Unicast</AFName>
                                            </Naming>
                                            <Enable>true</Enable>
                                        </GlobalAF>
                                    </GlobalAFTable>
                                </Global>
                                <BGPEntity>
                                    <NeighborTable>
                                        <Neighbor>
                                            <Naming>
                                                <NeighborAddress>
                                                    <IPV4Address>41.41.41.42</IPV4Address>
                                                </NeighborAddress>
                                            </Naming>
                                            <RemoteAS>
                                                <AS_XX>0</AS_XX>
                                                <AS_YY>65535</AS_YY>
                                            </RemoteAS>
                                            <NeighborAFTable>
                                                <NeighborAF>
                                                    <Naming>
                                                        <AFName>IPv4Unicast</AFName>
                                                    </Naming>
                                                    <Activate>true</Activate>
                                                    <RoutePolicyIn>ATLFGTSDW01_HUB_IN</RoutePolicyIn>
                                                    <RoutePolicyOut>DENY-ALL</RoutePolicyOut>
                                                    <SoftReconfiguration>
                                                        <InboundSoft>true</InboundSoft>
                                                        <SoftAlways>true</SoftAlways>
                                                    </SoftReconfiguration>
                                                </NeighborAF>
                                            </NeighborAFTable>
                                        </Neighbor>
                                    </NeighborTable>
                                </BGPEntity>
                            </DefaultVRF>
                        </FourByteAS>
                    </InstanceAS>
                </Instance>
            </BGP>
        </Configuration>
    </Set>
</Request>
```

Comment: `XML>` Like the error says "Start tag expected, '<' not found" It is expecting `<XML>` But it looks like `XML>` should not be there at all.

Comment: That fixed one of my issues.  The next issue I am having is that my config does not seem to start with <config> like edit config wants.  By doing one change at a time it works.  This is the config changes I want to issue to the router.  What would the correct format for issuing this config look like?  Or am I stuck to issuing one change at a time?